# PreferenceCategory theme not applied to PreferenceScreen

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-layout

I saw lots of answers and threads regarding this problem alone with tutorials for how to create custom PreferenceCategory. Nothing works for me. My theme just not applied.

PreferenceActivity class:

```
public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity{

private MyPreferenceFragment preferences;

@Override   
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preferences = new MyPreferenceFragment();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, preferences).commit();
}

public static class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.mypreferences);            
    }      
}   
}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<activity android:name="com.gpsy.preferences.PreferencesActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"             
            android:theme="@style/Custom">
</activity>
```

styles.xml:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="PreferenceListHeader" >
    <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/Gray</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingBottom">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">12dp</item>
</style>

<style name="Custom" parent="@android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/PreferenceListHeader</item>               
</style>
</resources>
```

mypreferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/gps_settings">

    <ListPreference
            android:key="nav_systems_preference"
            android:title="@string/my_nav_app"
            android:summary="summary_checkbox_preference"/>

</PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Also, I tried to apply theme the following way without success:

```
setTheme(R.style.Custom);
```

Tryed to change PreferenceCategory tag to

```
<PreferenceCategory android:widgetLayout="@style/Custom"
        android:title="@string/gps_settings">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your theme is not working because you did not set `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_weight` nor could it be inherited from a parent (which is not given).

For `<style name="PreferenceListHeader" >`, just add the following:

```
<item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
<item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
```

You don't need `setTheme(R.style.Custom);` or `android:widgetLayout="@style/Custom"` then. You can't provide a style to `android:widgetLayout`, anyway. You would have to provide a layout resource that contains just a TextView. But if you choose to use the style (see above), you don't need to set the layout.

Comment: HI! I had a similar problem, with almost exactly the same code as @Mike. My problem is that i had a background attribute with the drawable used for the line separator (by default is grey) and its makes the background of ALL the textview grey... I have correctly set width and height but i cant understand what i'm doing wrong... ANy clues? Anyone had the same problem?